# How to show the username on every page using Spring MVC, Spring Security and FreeMarker

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, freemarker

How can I show the username of a user that logged in on the header of every page, I try using the following methods

1) this spring security tags like this:

first I create a variable security like this

```
<#assign security=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"] />
```

and then I try to get the username using this `authentication` tag method that I investigated

```
<@security.authentication  property="principal.username"> 

</@security.authentication>
```

but I get this error

```
    FreeMarker template error:
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'principal.username' of bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken]: Bean property 'principal.username' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

2) I tried getting the username in the controllers and put it in the view like this

```
 Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
 String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username

    map.addAttribute("username" , name);
```

that worked but I have too many controllers and I don't want to update all my controllers and put those lines in all my controllers.

those are my versions

```
<spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.security.version>

<artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
<version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>

<artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
<version>2.3.21</version>
```

Any solution is welcome thanks

Comment: Instead of `principal.username` use `name` or `principal.name`. The `Principal` class indeed doesn't have a property `username` it has a property name. (Which would be easy to check if you check the api of `Principal`).

Comment: thanks that were the problem, I used the following line to display the username `<@security.authentication  property="name"> 
                    </@security.authentication>`and it worked thanks,
 but I checked the API and they show me this example `<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />` and that example didn't work it showed me error that put in my question. this is the API I checked http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e6333

Comment: It's not related to your problem, but note that you are using a rather old FreeMarker version. That can cost you, because of less helpful error messages for example.

Comment: Actually it looks like Freemarker isn't handling the expression properly, it should actually work. Have you tried a more recent version of Freemarker. Like 2.3.23 (not sure what the incubating 24 and 25 versions are...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the expression doesn't resolve to the following Java call when used in Freemarker. (It has been too long for me to remember the exact syntax).

```
authentication.getPrincipal().getUsername();
```

This is also what the exception hints at that it cannot find the property named `principal.username`. Instead just write `name` which will get the `name` property of the current `Authentication` object.

```
<@security.authentication  property="name">
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
${Session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.authentication.name}
```